# Flutter: How to fix a container at the Bottom over all the screens on the App

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

I want to use Ad mob on my app, but I want to use the same ad for all screens on my app. So one ad at the bottom of the screen, that dosn't change by navigating through the app.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bottomSheet` and place the widget based on your need.

```dart
return Scaffold(
  bottomSheet: showWidget ? Text("ad-banner") : null,
```

Comment: where do I have to write this code? in which screen? I was not able to finde showWidget

Comment: `showWidget` is just a bool to control visibility, you can directly put ad here

Comment: it didnot work, dose it make any differents if i change screnns or routs?

Comment: Screens/Views and routes are two different things, consider including your current snippet for better understanding